# Docker Swarm safely remove node in global mode

Tags: docker, nginx, swarm

### Current status:

I got swarm up and running with 1 master and 2 worker nodes running in **global** mode, where each node serves an nginx server. The service is required to run in global mode.

### Goal:

Now I want to scale down the whole swarm to 1 master node and 1 worker node without losing any requests. Meaning to safely remove 1 worker node.

### Plan:

My current plan is to put 1 worker node into drain availability to safely (?) remove it from the swarm.
But as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767213/does-a-drained-docker-swarm-manager-node-still-participate-the-routing-mesh-ing) drained nodes still participate in the routing mesh.

The docker documentation says, that

> DRAIN availability prevents a node from receiving new tasks from the swarm manager. It also means the manager stops tasks running on the node and launches replica tasks on a node with ACTIVE availability.

> Setting a node to DRAIN does not remove standalone containers from that node, such as those created with docker run, docker compose up, or the Docker Engine API. A node's status, including DRAIN, only affects the node's ability to schedule swarm service workloads.

### Question:

Does the routing mesh still route **new** requests to the drained node? In this case they would time out when I remove the drained node from the swarm. If it does not, but keeps the container running - perfect! Old requests would then be answered.

Im a bit confused about the words *workload* and *tasks* in the documentation. Does it include routing new requests to the node?